# Business Objects Results Limit 65529

Tags: excel, business-objects, business-intelligence

I cannot seem to find any concrete answers for this.

I have a client that has been exporting to excel a great number of rows. Recently, the total number of results has hit 65529 and stayed there, even though it should be increasing.

Is there any way around the cap?

Also, we are using XI, but are about to switch over to xI 3.1. Will the cap therefore be different when we switch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there is not.

You may want to consider CSV (Comma Separated Values) format which is unlimited and opens in excel but only the first 65529 rows.

Excel 2007 has been extended to 1 million rows. See http://visio.mvps.org/Excel_2007.htm

Comment: Excel supports only 64k rows.

Comment: So the cap is imposed by excel then? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Wes In Excel 2007, the row limit is over a million.

Comment: One option with Excel xls files is to start populating a second worksheet within the workbook when you hit the 65529 rows point

Comment: @ Remou Thanks, although I have no control over what version of Excel the client uses.

Comment: @ Mark Baker How would I do this using a single query in a webi report?

Comment: @wes - no idea. I know how to do it in some languages, with some libraries; but I'm not familiar with your tools.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again for your help